# Moving Windows system reserved partition

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, partitioning, boot-partition

I just installed the Windows as a dual boot. I've decided I want to expand my Windows partition, but in between the Windows partition, which I want to make bigger, and my Linux partition, which I want to make smaller, is the 100 mb system reserved partition. What can I do about this? Can I move it or delete it? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Partitions can be moved if there's unallocated space after it but it's riskier than just resizing. In order to do what you want you would need to shrink the Linux partition, then move that and the recovery partition to the right. Only then you'd be able to grow the Windows system partition. Risky but doable, make sure you have backups. Perhaps better to make recovery media in Windows and just delete the recovery partition.

Comment: How would I delete the recovery partition? And why is that so risky? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, if you're asking so many basic questions about partitions, better leave them alone, even experts can and do make mistakes. Always backup first because https://superuser.com/a/402632/772515

Comment: I understand how to delete them. What I wanted to know was how to delete it without killing windows.

Comment: The recovery partition isn't required to boot Windows.

Comment: It isn't? I guess I can just delete it then